# How to write AWS Log Insights query for multiple string patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to write a log insights query to search for multiple string patterns in log groups.

I know that I can use the following query to find a specific string in logs :

```
 fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "test string"
| sort @timestamp desc
```

But, I want to extend this to find multiple string patterns with regular expressions.

Can someone help to understand how to achieve this. I tried looking in internet and reading aws document but could not figure out how to do.

Comment: Any particular pattern you want to filter?

Comment: @OmarRosadio I am trying to do breach monitoring for log4jshell issue .. so looking for patterns like : jndi: etc

Answer (score 1):

How about using slashes, rather than quotes. That searches a regex pattern:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /test string/
| sort @timestamp desc
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Answer (score 1):

I use the bellow syntax when I search for multiple strings:

1. Match all messages that have both 'string1' and 'string2':

   ````
   fields @timestamp, @message 
   | filter @message like 'string1' and  @message like 'string2'
   | sort @timestamp desc
   | limit 20```
   ````
2. Match all messages that have either 'string1' or 'string2':

   ````
   fields @timestamp, @message
   | filter @message like 'string1' or  @message like 'string2'
   | sort @timestamp desc
   | limit 20```
   ````